logs routing sink based on textPayload
Using GCP router logs sink I would like to filter out some logs that are just spamming me.
In the past I did something like
jsonPayload.msg="GET /internal/prometheus [200 OK]"

which works fine but with textPayload it doesn't seem to have any effect. Currently the metrics and internal health checks are being printing in textPayload.
I have:
textPayload=~"(.)200(.)OK"
Has anyone been able to filter logs based on textPayload before?

There's no reason why your filter would not work although it's unclear to me whether there's any value in the capture groups. I assume that you have log entries that match your filter. Please consider updating your question to include some examples of the log entries that you're trying to filter.

In GCE and GKE custom logging labels prevent using from having a textPayload in this log entry, but you will have a jsonPayload with a "message" field
